# 90's Horror movie - Husband dies and return as an evil spirit

Tags: identify-this-movie

The film centers around a married couple, and at one point, the husband dies, and his spirit comes out. Then, somehow he comes back, but as a demon. Later on, in the movie, the wife finds out that her husband isn't who he really is. So, she manages to save her husband's soul, and fight off the demon. Afterwards, the couple move out of their home, and they show the husband in bandages, along with a cast on his arm. Then, the couple get into the moving truck and drive away.

This film is from the 1990's, and the front cover of the movie shows the demon in the form of the husband, as one side of its face looks human and the other is demonic.

Comment: Glad you found the movie! You can put that in an answer and accept it, rather than editing it into the body of the question.

Comment: Thanks, F1Krazy. It's better to do that, other than making the body section too long.

Answer (score 3):

What you actually saw was an episode of ***Hammer House of Horror the Tv Series*** Ep 12: Two faces of evil.

[Here's a more detailed explanation of the plot](http://www.hammerhouseofhorrorguide.co.uk/hammer-house-of-horror-the-two-faces-of-evil.htm)

The last scene that you described:

> After fleeing the clutches of a demented Martin, Janet reaches the farm and hides away in the barn. In there she sees her son - he is dead! A copy of her son is also in the barn, and he is acting in the same way as Martin. Janet escapes the barn and falls into the arms of Mr Roberts, the farm owner. Mr Roberts calls for an ambulance. Janet is taken away in the ambulance and there driving is a copy of Janet!

The cover that you talked about:

[image: Cover of the episode]

Hope this is it =)

Comment: Sorry, Gustavo Gabriel. But, this isn't the one I was thinking of. I just researched on this episode, and it said that it aired in 1980. However, what I was talking about is actually a full-length movie from the 1990's, and I could tell that the movie was brand-new at the time. Also, the wardrobe and the hairstyles worn in the movie definitely looked '90s.

Comment: No worries, But the cover and the last scene with the ambulance were too much similar to not be mistaken. Good Luck then =)